# Read file into spring controller. Using relative path

Tags: java, file, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

i want to read file from controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHomePage(ModelMap model) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        List<User> users = XmlParser.parse("Sum_and_clients.xml");
        return "home";
    }
```

But when I start the server it wants download it from apache-tomcat\bin.  Despite the fact that  Sum_and_clients.xml is located near the HomeController.java. How change this absoulte  tomcat path, to path in my project?

Comment: is the xml file in your classpath or just somewhere in the webapp?

Comment: HomeCtrl. is a class, so its located in the classpath. Search for loading files from the classpath and where to place files in webapps.

Comment: @Ria I want to put it in any directory inside my application.

Comment: @Stefan You mean, that I can get absolute location of HomeController with his ClassLoader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

```
  URL url = HomeController.class.getResource("Sum_and_clients.xml");
  File file = new File(url.getPath())
```

This file should be placed into [{Your project name}\target\ {Your project name} \WEB-INF\classes\ {Your package to HomeController}